# How to Show Hidden Content Block via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I have the following html:

```
<div class="contentBlock">
  <div><img src="images/help.png" alt="help button" class="helpButton"></div>
  <div class="helpBlock">
    <p>...some hidden text...</p>
  </div> <!-- end .helpBlock -->
  <h2>A Header</h2>
  <p>...some visible text...</p>
</div> <!-- end .contentBlock -->
```

I have the following css:

```
div.contentBlock {
  position: relative; /* required for z-index */
  z-index: 1; /* interacts with div.helpBlock */
}
div.helpBlock {
  display: none;
  position: relative; /* required for z-index */
  z-index: 10; /* interacts with div.contentBlock */
}
```

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show helpBlock on page
  $('img.helpButton').click(function(){
    /*$(this).closest('.helpBlock').show();*/ // does not work
    /*$(this).closest('.helpBlock').css('display');*/ // does not work
    var $contentWrapper = $(this).closest('.helpBlock');
    var $siblings = $contentWrapper.siblings('.helpBlock');
    $siblings.find('.helpBlock').show(); // does not work
  });
  // end Show helpBlock
}) // end jQuery Functions
```

I am trying to get the .helpBlock to display when I click the help button but none of my jquery is working.

Can anyone assist?

THanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your button is encased in a DIV, it will not use .closest() or .find(). You are already clicking on the button, you can use `$(this)` and navigate from there with [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and then [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(this).parent().next('.helpBlock').show();
```

That should work. This should also eliminate the unnecessary variables:

```
var $contentWrapper = $(this).closest('.helpBlock');
var $siblings = $contentWrapper.siblings('.helpBlock');
```

Comment: please consider marking this answer with the checkbox to show that if fixed your problem :)

Comment: Gotta wait 10 minutes -- which I hate about this site. I'll be gone onto other things in 10 minutes so I'll need to come back at a later time. Wish SO would not be so restrictive

Comment: Will consider it next time around @Jean-François Côté  unless SO shortens their restriction period

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$('img.helpButton').click(function(){
   var $contentWrapper = $(this).parent();
   var $siblings = $contentWrapper.siblings('.helpBlock');
   $siblings.show();
});
```

if you want a one liner:

```
$('img.helpButton').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().siblings('.helpBlock').show();
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks @Jai. I am going to go with (at)LifeInTheGrey 's answer because I already embedded it and it worked plus it is syntactically lighter.

Comment: Okay Great go with that but you can make it one liner too.